# Entity Framework 5 Code first adding an image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am writing a very small application with mvc4 and entity framework 5.

I want to add a product and store and image for the product.

I have a model

```
  [Table("CatalogItem")]
public class CatalogItemModel
{
    [Key]
    public int CatalogItemId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }

    public int ProductCount { get; set; }

    public string Size { get; set; }

    public string Sku { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "image")]


    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Display Catalog Item")]
    public bool DisplayItem { get; set; }
}
```

My controller. This never gets hit.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CatalogItemModel catalogitemmodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.CatalogItemModels.Add(catalogitemmodel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(catalogitemmodel);
    }
```

My views form

```
    <fieldset>
    <legend>CatalogItemModel</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductCount)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductCount)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductCount)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Size)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Size)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Size)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sku)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sku)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sku)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayItem)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayItem)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayItem)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Image)
    </div>

    <input name="Image" type="file"/>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

When I try posting a new catalog with an image within my file input however it throws an error

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Comment: Can you add the code where you assign the image?

Comment: @NickW just added the controller action. I have added a breakpoint however it never gets hit

Comment: What about `catalogitemmodel`? How does this get created? If your breakpoint is not getting hit then the problem is earlier on.

Comment: Sorry I am trying out code first so it takes care of it for me

Comment: What I mean is, what is the code at the point you are assigning the byte array of your image to `CatalogItemModel.Image`?

Comment: I am not really to sure how I am meant to do that. Should I be using a different property to byte[]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to fix like that:

1 . Replace

`<input name="Image" type="file"/>` 
with `<input name="ImageFile" type="file"/>`

2 . In controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(CatalogItemModel catalogitemmodel, HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ImageFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                catalogitemmodel.Image =  ms.ToArray();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.CatalogItemModels.Add(catalogitemmodel);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(catalogitemmodel);
        }
```

Comment: thanks @testCoder however ImageFile is always returned as null. I have checked that the spelling is correct however no joy

Comment: using var files = Request.Files I was able to get the image

Comment: DiverDan do not forget this: @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })