# User profile image asp.net mvc identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, image-uploading, asp.net-identity, user-profile

I'm creating a web application using MVC 5 and Identity. I have so far created a registration system, but I would like to allow users to upload a profile when they register.

I was wondering if it is possible to implement profile pictures with asp.net identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing todo is to create a second table (or add a column to the current table), add a file upload feature to the registration form. When registration is successful add the picture to the db with EntityFramework. Create a page to return the picture by the userid so you can include it in a page somewhere.

Something like this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx but with a profile picture

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Assuming you're using the default Entity Framework implementation, you can extend the `ApplicationUser` in a file called `Models/IdentityModels.cs`.

You can store the image in the database or elsewhere on the file system.

One way to store it in the database is using a byte array in the model (which I believe maps to `varbinary(max)`)...

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

Details on how to save upload an image and save in the database via EF can be found here...
[Entity Framework 5 Code first adding an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174593/entity-framework-5-code-first-adding-an-image)

Or you can simply save the uploaded file to the file system or to blob storage, then store the path or URL to the image...

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```