# Taking an image and storing as string it from user using .net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am a student developer in .Net MVC 5 and I want to insert image from new user to my database. I found a lot of method for byte[] data type but according to my researchs , there is no source for string data type.(Example; [Entity Framework 5 Code first adding an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174593/entity-framework-5-code-first-adding-an-image#)) . What can i do for string column of ImageUrl in my database? Could you help me at this issue ?

My Model :

```
public class usersModel{
public string userImageUrl{get;set;}
}
```

My Controller :

```
 public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        AgmEntities db = new AgmEntities();

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View("Create", new usersModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(usersModel uModel,HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                return View("Create");
            }

            var user = new Users();

            if(file !=null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string imgPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/User_Images/"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(imgPath);
            }
            user.userImageUrl = "~/User_Images/" + file.FileName;/*Error line*/
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

My cshtml :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userImageUrl, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" name="ImageFile" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userImageUrl, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: To store strings you can use `varchar` or `nvarchar` types in your database

Comment: Or is that not your question? It's unclear. What actual problem are you experiencing with the code above?

Comment: I mean my method is working exactly but i can't save image file as url to my database column. I am facing an error on this line `user.userImageUrl = "~/User_Images/" + file.FileName;`  while inserting. Is it clear now ?

Comment: You got it @ADyson ?

Comment: "can't" isn't an error message or problem statement that anyone can fix. What happens when you do this? An error? Unexpected outcome? Please be clear and specific about the issue. I think the answer below is probably correct but it would be easier for everyone if you give a more exact description of what happens in your code.

Comment: When i ask a question  from here , i will be more careful to your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add new `{ enctype="multipart/form-data"}` to your form to allow upload file.

```
Html.BeginForm(
    null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data"})
```

Change cshtml code to:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(
    null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data"})) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userImageUrl, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" name="ImageFile" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userImageUrl, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

and move this line of code inside `if user.userImageUrl = "~/User_Images/" + file.FileName;/*Error line*/` 
in this case `file.FileName` may be null.

```
 if(file !=null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string imgPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/User_Images/"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(imgPath);
                user.userImageUrl = "~/User_Images/" + file.FileName;/*Error line*/
            }
```

One more note that need change `parameter name` in action same as `name of input` type file:

```
<input type="file" name="ImageFile" /> to <input type="file" name="file" />
```

Comment: I did it and also answer is so logical but  although i add a photo in from form area ,  userImageUrl column in MsSQL is Null. Creating is succesful but while sending file , ı am facing Null area. What might be problem ?

Comment: did you debug that user.userImageUrl has value?

Comment: `file.FileName` gives an error like  file.FileName = 'file.FileName' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'  when i examine with break point. It should be wrong method.

Comment: did you move user.userImageUrl = "~/User_Images/" + file.FileName; inside if(file !=null && file.ContentLength > 0) ?

Comment: Of course i moved it inside scopes. Code is working correctly but i saw an error on `file.FileName`  with break point @hien-nguyen

Comment: Did you put new { enctype="multipart/form-data"} to begin form?

Comment: I did everything which you wrote me.

Comment: Can you change <input type="file" name="ImageFile" /> to <input type="file" name="file" /> ?

Comment: Okay. That one was true. It worked exactly now. I am taking url from image file. Thank you a lot to interest in my question.